# CFML sql query modifying original date format from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cfml

Say I have the following date format in my SQL Server database: `3/2007` but when I try to get the data via CFML script I get it this altered format `2007-03-31 00:00:00.0`, my script looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="header" datasource="mydb">
SELECT 
  ExpDate
FROM 
  myTable
</cfquery>

<CFOUTPUT>ExpDate</CFOUTPUT>
<cfloop query="header">
<CFOUTPUT>#ExpDate#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Any idea why my date format is altered? Thanks!

Comment: *RE: I have the following date format in my SQL Server database: 3/2007*. Is the column `datetime` or `varchar`? As mentioned, `datetime` values are not stored that way. SQL Server actually [stores datetime values as numbers internally](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258277%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx). *RE: I get it this altered format 2007-03-31 00:00:00.0* That is the default format CF uses when displaying a datetime value as a string. If you want a different format, use `DateFormat(theDateTimeColumn, mask)` (as you figured out). Note: No need for `ParseDateTime` here. It is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates are not stored in any format in SQL Server. A client application formats dates.

You can modify your query as follows to get date as `varchar` value  in needed format.

```
SELECT 
  RIGHT(CONVERT(varchar(12),ExpDate,103),7) ExpDate
FROM 
  myTable
```

Comment: Did that now I get this error in my script when trying to output: `Variable EXPDATE is undefined.`

Comment: @xtmtrx I forgot to specify alias for the field. Please, see my answer I just edited it.

Comment: Oh, thanks! Anyway I found another way with CFML `#DateFormat(ParseDateTime(ExpDate),"mm/yyyy")#`